# GoLang JSON decoding

Tags: json, go

Please read the question before flagging it.

```
  {
      "out_key": {
      "some_uri": "url",
      "more_than_one_key_here": {
           "Ip": "127.0.0.1",
           "port": "80",
       }
    }
  }
```

`out_key` is dynamically created. There is no guessing the name of it.
Similarly, `more_than_one_key_here` is also dynamically created. `some_uri` will remain constant under `out_key`. In such a scenario, how do I create a struct for decoding the JSON?

Comment: Why not use a map instead of a struct?

Comment: I tried assigning type morekey map[string]struct_for_ip_port and creating another struct that took both "some_url" and "morekey" struct. It does not seem to be working. plus, "morekey" will have to referred via "morekey" rather than substituting "morekey" with the actual key name. That is not desired.

Comment: Can you show then an example of what you're looking for? If you want dynamic keys you need to use a map, so if a map doesn't suffice I don't understand what it is you want.

Comment: Have you tried the type: `map[string]map[string]interface{}`?

Comment: I'm confused by the comment '"morekey" will have to referred via "morekey" rather than substituting "morekey" with the actual key name. That is not desired.' If you don't know the key until runtime, how will you refer to it using that key at compile time?

Comment: Here is how to decode into a map: https://play.golang.org/p/yYpjRR-BKa - if that doesn't work for you, explain why it doesn't work and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is it enough to extract the IP and port and ignore the keys or do you actually need the later?

Answer (score 2):

In Go field names of a struct have to be known at compile time. So, in your case a struct type is not appropriate. Alternatively, you can use a map.

Let's say, that you are only interested in the IP and port values. Then you can ignore the keys of the JSON object altogether.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

const data = `{
    "out_key": {
        "some_uri": "url",
        "more_than_one_key_here": {
            "Ip": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "80"
        }
    }
}`

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]map[string]interface{})
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to parse JSON: %v", err)
    }

    for _, value := range m {
        for _, value := range value {
            m, ok := value.(map[string]interface{})
            if ok {
                fmt.Printf("IP: %s\n", m["Ip"])
                fmt.Printf("Port: %s\n", m["port"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You could create a struct for the Ip and Port and a separate one for one of the keys.

```
type data struct{
    Ip   string
    port string
}

type DynamicKey map[string]data
```

Then once you decode the json and have the dynamic key, let's say for example it is (rando_key) you can do this

```
fmt.Println(DynamicKey[rando_key].Ip, DynamicKey[rando_key].port)
```

This is off course for only one of the keys but it is possible to repeat the process.